# How do I send javascript FormData() object with POST method and present that data on the new requested page?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post, fetch

I want to send a javascript FormData() object to another php page and load that page using POST method.
I know how to send FormData() object using ajax/fetch method in javascript to requested page and retrieve processed data back to the page that made the request.
How do I send javascript FormData() object with POST method and present that data on the new requested page?

Comment: `How do I send javascript FormData() object with POST method` .... do you mean without AJAX/Fetch?

Comment: I would be interested in both with and without. My impression is that I have to serialize object without ajax/fetch

Comment: `FormData` is really intended to be used with AJAX rather than without. With `Fetch` is is supplied as the `body` parameter for the request, similarly with regular AJAX. Without either XMLHttpRequest or Fetch you are making life more difficult for yourself as you could, probably, iterate through FormData and build your own form to submit

Comment: Is it possible to load requested page with ajax/fetch at the same time as passing the FormData() object?